# can I deploy two different rails app with two different ruby versions on same vps using passenger+apache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, passenger, httpd.conf

I have a server running on cent os & I have installed apache2 & passenger on it.
In httpd.conf I am having following configuration to load passenger

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

So according to this configuration I can deploy apps on this server that runs using ruby 1.8.
But now my problem is if I want to deploy a app which is using ruby 1.9.2 then?
What should I do? Is it possible? Please help

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this link for apche/nginx running on two ruby version

http://robaldred.co.uk/2011/06/running-passenger-with-multiple-different-ruby-versions-apache-nginx-rvm/